# Keep nodes within specific clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot

I've been looking over the GraphViz docs and stackoverflow for the last hour, but can't find a solution to this problem. I have several clusters in my dot file, and I need certain nodes to stay within specific clusters. Some of the nodes have relationships with nodes in other clusters. It seems every time I save the file, a few of the nodes jump between different clusters. Is there a way to define a node as always being part of a specific cluster?

Comment: I've never seen that behavior. Every time I've added a node to a correctly declared cluster, it has always stayed in that cluster. Also when you say "every time I save the file, a few of the nodes jump", are you using a text editor and processing the text file with dot, or are you using some other tool? If you are willing to share your problematic dot file, we might be better able to help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out how to avoid this issue.

I was defining both the nodes and the edges within the subgraphs, so I think it was getting confused when edges included nodes that should not be contained within the subgraph.

Instead, I just only define the nodes (all the nodes) within the subgraphs, and define the edges afterwards all together at the end of the file. Works like a champ :)